# For web.config update, is an app pool cycle required on IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis

After a web.config is updated on a Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 site, does the app pool automatically cycle?  If so, is the cycle based upon a set of time or does this happen immediately?  Just want to know if I  need to force an app pool cycle to see a web.config change within a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no... the application pool doesn't recycle when the web.config is updated.

**Explanation**
Application Domain is the one that gets recycled. If you check the Application Pool settings in IIS, it will list the conditions under which the pool is supposed to recycle.

Application domain recycle, on the other hand is a virtual entity. It gets recycled under various conditions. Web.config change is just one of them. Read more about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david.wang/2006/03/13/thoughts-on-iis-configuration-changes-and-when-it-takes-effect/) and [here](https://www.treeloop.com/blog/iis-application-domain-and-pool-recycling)